# How do I pass on the search string from one class to another?

Tags: android

I have a search View which is defined as follows in a class basesearch.java:

```
protected  EditText mSearchView;
```

(It refers to the basic textbox search view).

```
Now in class searchfragment.java, I have the following method:
private void runSearch(final String searchTerm) {
        if(searchTerm.contains(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase() + " " + mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase())){
        AWebViewFragment.newInstanceForSearch(getFragmentManager(), null, null);
        }else {
            SearchResultsFragment.newInstance(getFragmentManager(), searchTerm);
        }
    }
```

Note: mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase() is getting the typed in search value. 
 Now, I want to use this value "mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase()" and pass it on to another class which is being called "AWebViewFragment" in the first if clause.
I am defining the AwebViewfragment as follwos:

```
public static String OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT = "https://mobile13.cp.com/msf1.0/fwd/answers/service/v1/?q="+mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase()+"%20revenue&ui.theme=novadark&uuid=PADACT-002&userAgent=iphone";
```

However it throws an error at mSearchView,unless I set some dummy value defining it. I want it to be able to get information from previous class for the typed in search term. I wonder what I am doing wrong. I want the url to display with the dynamically typed search term. Is it possible to do the same somehow? Feel free to modify the code and walk me thru a new change, I will try any suggestions for new code or improvements. Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Justin
Also, I am already using the bundles in Awebviewfragment:

```
private static AWebViewFragment __newInstance(final AnswersWebViewFragment fragment, final FragmentManager manager,
            final String searchTerm, final String symbolType, int containerViewId, final int inAnimation, final int outAnimation, final int popInAnimation, final int popOutAnimation) {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(SEARCH_TERM, searchTerm);
        bundle.putString(AnswersWebViewFragment.SYMBOL_TYPE, symbolType);
        bundle.putInt(AnswersWebViewFragment.CONTAINER_ID, containerViewId);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD, containerViewId);
        fragmentInfo.setAnimation(inAnimation, outAnimation);
        fragmentInfo.setPopAnimation(popInAnimation, popOutAnimation);
        fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_A_FRAGMENT_WEBVIEW);
        fragmentInfo.setActionBarTitle(Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.nav_option_quotes));
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);

        return fragment;
    }
```

And OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT is defined outside the method for bundle, how do i retrieve the search term passed on from the previous class?
and oncreate I am using :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSearchTerm = getArguments().getString(SEARCH_TERM);
}
```

ENTIRE CODE BELOW:

```
AbssearchAutisuggestFragment:


public abstract class AbsSearchAutoSuggestFragment extends AbsLoaderFragment implements SearchAutoSuggestObserver, SearchAutoSuggestItemClickListener{

    protected  EditText mSearchView;
    protected ListView mSearchListView;

    private SearchAutoSuggestsTask mSearchAutoSuggestTask;
    private List<SearchAutoSuggestRow> mSearchAutoSuggestRows;

    public void startSearchAutoSuggestTask(final String searchTerm) {
        killLastSearchAutoSuggestTask();
        mSearchAutoSuggestTask = new SearchAutoSuggestsTask(this);
        final String params[] = {searchTerm};
        mSearchAutoSuggestTask.execute(params);
    }

    public boolean killLastSearchAutoSuggestTask() {
        if (mSearchAutoSuggestTask != null) {
            mSearchAutoSuggestTask.cancel();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void onSearchAutoSuggestAvailable(final SearchAutoSuggests searchAutoSuggests) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity == null) {
            return;
        }

        mSearchAutoSuggestRows = populateSearchAutoSuggestRows(searchAutoSuggests);
        final SearchAutoSuggestAdapter adapter = new SearchAutoSuggestAdapter(activity, R.layout.item_search_history_auto_suggest, mSearchAutoSuggestRows);
        adapter.setOnItemClickedListener(this);
        mSearchListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        onHasResults();
    }

    private List<SearchAutoSuggestRow> populateSearchAutoSuggestRows(final SearchAutoSuggests searchAutoSuggests) {
        final List<SearchAutoSuggestRow> searchAutoSuggestRows = new ArrayList<SearchAutoSuggestRow>();

        for (final SearchAutoSuggest searchAutoSuggest : searchAutoSuggests.getSearchAutoSuggests()) {
            final SearchAutoSuggestHeader header = new SearchAutoSuggestHeader(searchAutoSuggest.getName().toUpperCase());
            searchAutoSuggestRows.add(header);
            int i = 1;
            for (final SearchAutoSuggestHits searchAutoSuggestHits : searchAutoSuggest.getHits()) {
                final String id = searchAutoSuggestHits.getId();
                final String title = searchAutoSuggestHits.getTitle();
                final String subTitle = searchAutoSuggestHits.getSubtitle();
                final String symbol = searchAutoSuggestHits.getSymbol();
                final String st = searchAutoSuggestHits.getSt();
                final Spanned formattedTitle = formatAutoSuggestText(title);
                final Spanned formattedSymbol = formatAutoSuggestText(symbol);
                final SearchAutoSuggestItem searchAutoSuggestItem =  new SearchAutoSuggestItem(id, formattedTitle, subTitle, formattedSymbol,st);
                searchAutoSuggestRows.add(searchAutoSuggestItem);
                if(i==3){
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        return searchAutoSuggestRows;
    }


    private Spanned formatAutoSuggestText(final String autoSuggestText) {
        if (autoSuggestText == null) {
            return Html.fromHtml("");
        }

        try {
            String modifiedAutoSuggestText= "" ;
            final String searchText = mSearchView.getText().toString();
            final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(StringUtils.INSENSITIVE_CASE + searchText);
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(autoSuggestText);  // TODO: figure out why this line throws NPE "at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:290)"
            int end = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                final String subStringMatchFound = autoSuggestText.substring(end, matcher.end());
                final String stringToBeReplaced = autoSuggestText.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                final String stringToReplace = "<b><font color='" + getResources().getColor(R.color.search_autosuggest_highlighted_text) + "'>" +matcher.group()+ "</font></b>";
                modifiedAutoSuggestText += subStringMatchFound.replace(stringToBeReplaced,stringToReplace);
                end = matcher.end();
            }
            modifiedAutoSuggestText += autoSuggestText.substring(end);
            return Html.fromHtml(modifiedAutoSuggestText);
        }
        catch (final Exception e){
            return Html.fromHtml(autoSuggestText);
        }

    }

    public void onHasResults() {
        if (getView() == null) {
            Log.d("Search Issues", "view is null");
            return;
        }
        LayoutUtils.showResults(getView(), R.id.search_history_auto_suggest_list);
    }

    public void onLoading() {
        LayoutUtils.showLoading(getView(), R.id.search_history_auto_suggest_list);
    }

    public void onNoResults() {
        View view = getView().findViewById(R.id.overlay);
        if (view != null) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

SearchHistoryAutosuggestFragment:

public class SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment extends AbsSearchAutoSuggestFragment
        implements ViewBinder, SearchHistoryItemClickListener,  OnClickListener, MainActivity.BackPressListener {

```
public final static String TAG_SEARCH_HISTORY_AUTO_SUGGEST_FRAGMENT = "SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment";

private SearchHistoryListAdapter mAdapter;
private TextWatcher mTextWatcher;

private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
    SearchHistory.Columns.SEARCH_TERM,
    SearchHistory.Columns.SEARCH_HISTORY_META_DATA,
    SearchHistory.Columns.SEARCH_SYMBOL
};

private static final int[] VIEW_IDS = {
    R.id.search_item,
    R.id.search_history_metadata,
    R.id.search_symbol
};

public static SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment newInstance(final FragmentManager manager) {

    final SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment fragment = new SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment();
    final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD);
    fragmentInfo.setAnimation(R.anim.slide_in_from_top, 0);
    fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_SEARCH_HISTORY_AUTO_SUGGEST_FRAGMENT);
    FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);


    return fragment;
}

public static void removeInstance(final FragmentManager manager) {
    final SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment fragment = (SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_SEARCH_HISTORY_AUTO_SUGGEST_FRAGMENT);
    if (fragment == null) {
        return;
    }

    final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.REMOVE);
    fragmentInfo.setAnimation(R.anim.slide_out_to_top, FragmentInfo.NO_ANIMATION);
    fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_SEARCH_HISTORY_AUTO_SUGGEST_FRAGMENT);
    final FragmentStackManager stackManager = FragmentStackManager.getInstance();
    if (stackManager.getTopFragment() instanceof SearchHistoryAutoSuggestFragment) {
        stackManager.popTopFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSearchView = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_text);

    mAdapter = new SearchHistoryListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_search_history_auto_suggest, null, COLUMN_NAMES, VIEW_IDS, 0);
    mAdapter.setViewBinder(this);

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_history_auto_suggest, container, false);

    mSearchListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_history_auto_suggest_list);
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickedListener(this);
    mSearchListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    setSearchLinkOnclickListener(view);
    setSearchViewTextChangedListener();
    setSearchViewKeyListener();

    return view;
}



@Override
public Uri onCreateContentUri() {
    return SearchContentProvider.SEARCH_HISTORY_URI;
}

@Override
public void onOperationStarted(final Uri uri) {
    onLoading();
}

@Override
public void onCursorLoaded(final Uri uri, final Cursor cursor) {
    super.onCursorLoaded(uri, cursor);
    if (!isOperationExecuting()){
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            onHasResults();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(final View view, final Cursor cursor, final int columnIndex) {
    Log.d("SearchHistoryIssue", "setting view value");
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.search_symbol:
        String symbol = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        View dash = parent.findViewById(R.id.search_dash);
        TextView symbolTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.search_symbol);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(symbol)) {
            symbolTextView.setText("");
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (dash != null) {
                dash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (dash != null) {
                dash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private void setSearchViewTextChangedListener(){
    mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {
            handleTextChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count,final int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            handleAfterTextChanged(s);
        }
    };

    mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
}


        private boolean enterButtonClicked = false;

        private void setSearchViewKeyListener(){
            mSearchView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(final View v, final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && !enterButtonClicked) {
                        final String searchString = mSearchView.getText().toString();
                        if(!searchString.isEmpty()){
                            showSearchResults(searchString);
                        }
                        enterButtonClicked = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    enterButtonClicked = false;
                    return false;
                }

            });
        }

private void handleTextChanged() {
    final View clearButton = ((View) mSearchView.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.clear_search_textbox);
    if (mSearchView.getText().length() > 0) {
        clearButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        handleTextClear(clearButton);
    }
    displaySearchLink();
}

private void handleAfterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
    if (s.length() != 0) {
        Log.d("AutoSuggest", "Auto Suggest - text pressed on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        startSearchAutoSuggestTask(s.toString());
    } else {
        displaySearchHistory();
    }
}

private void handleTextClear(final View clearButton) {
    clearButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final boolean autoSuggestActive = killLastSearchAutoSuggestTask();
    if (!autoSuggestActive) {
        displaySearchHistory();
    }
}

private void displaySearchHistory() {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity == null) {
        return;
    }

    mAdapter = new SearchHistoryListAdapter(activity, R.layout.item_search_history_auto_suggest, null, COLUMN_NAMES, VIEW_IDS, 0);
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickedListener(this);
    mAdapter.setViewBinder(this);
    mSearchListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Log.d("SearchHistoryIssue", "About to restart content loader");
    restartContentLoader();
}


public void showSearchResults(final String searchString) {
    runSearch(searchString);
    saveSearchHistory(searchString, null, null);
}

private void saveSearchHistory(final String searchString, final String historyMetaData, final String symbol) {
    final SearchHistory searchHistory = new SearchHistory(searchString, historyMetaData, symbol);
    DatabaseUtils.addEntryToSearchHistoryTable(searchHistory);
}

private void runSearch(final String searchTerm) {
    killLastSearchAutoSuggestTask();
    hideSearchView();
    if(searchTerm.contains(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase() + " " + mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase())){
    AnswersWebViewFragment.newInstanceForSearch(getFragmentManager(), null, null);
    }else {
        SearchResultsFragment.newInstance(getFragmentManager(), searchTerm);
    }
}



private void displaySearchLink() {
    final View view = getView();
    if (view != null) {
        final String searchText = mSearchView.getText().toString();
        final TextView searchLink = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_link);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(searchText)) {
            searchLink.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.search_for)+" \"" + searchText + "\"");
            searchLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            searchLink.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.search_link:
        final String searchText = mSearchView.getText().toString();
        showSearchResults(searchText);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onHistoryItemClicked(final int viewId, final String searchHistoryTerm, final String searchHistoryMetadata, final String searchHistorySymbol) {
    switch (viewId) {
    case R.id.search_history_item_container:
        saveSearchHistory(searchHistoryTerm, searchHistoryMetadata, searchHistorySymbol);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(searchHistoryMetadata)) {
            runSearch(searchHistoryTerm);
        } else {
            displayQuotes(searchHistoryTerm, searchHistoryMetadata, searchHistorySymbol);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.search_item_button:
        mSearchView.setText(searchHistoryTerm);
        mSearchView.requestFocus();
        mSearchView.setSelection(searchHistoryTerm.length());
        break;
    default:
    }

}

@Override
public void onAutoSuggestItemClicked(final View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.search_autosuggest_item_container:
        final String searchAutoSuggestTitle = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.search_autosuggest_item_name)).getText().toString();
        final String searchAutoSuggestSubTitle = (String) ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.search_autosuggest_item_subtitle)).getText();
        final String searchAutoSuggestSymbol = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.search_autosuggest_item_symbol)).getText().toString();
        saveSearchHistory(searchAutoSuggestTitle, searchAutoSuggestSubTitle, searchAutoSuggestSymbol);
        displayQuotes(searchAutoSuggestTitle, searchAutoSuggestSubTitle, searchAutoSuggestSymbol);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }


}

private void displayQuotes(final String searchAutoSuggestTitle, final String searchAutoSuggestSubTitle, final String searchAutoSuggestSymbol) {
    killLastSearchAutoSuggestTask();

    QuotesFragmentWebView.newInstanceForSearch(getFragmentManager(), searchAutoSuggestSymbol, null);

    hideSearchView();
}


private void showKeyboard() {
    final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    if (activity == null) {
        return;
    }

    final EditText searchText = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.search_text);
    KeyboardUtils.showKeyboard(searchText, activity);
}


};
```

}

Answerswebviewfragment:

```
    public class AnswersWebViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener , MainActivity.BackPressListener<Fragment> {
    public static String OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT = "https://.mobile13.cp.com/msf1.0/fwd/answers/answers/service/v1/?q="+[SEARCHTERM]+"%20revenue&ui.theme=novadark&uuid=PADACT-002&userAgent=iphone";
private static AnswersWebViewFragment __newInstance(final AnswersWebViewFragment fragment, final FragmentManager manager,
            final String searchTerm, final String symbolType, int containerViewId, final int inAnimation, final int outAnimation, final int popInAnimation, final int popOutAnimation) {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(SEARCH_TERM, searchTerm);
        bundle.putString(AnswersWebViewFragment.SYMBOL_TYPE, symbolType);
        bundle.putInt(AnswersWebViewFragment.CONTAINER_ID, containerViewId);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD, containerViewId);
        fragmentInfo.setAnimation(inAnimation, outAnimation);
        fragmentInfo.setPopAnimation(popInAnimation, popOutAnimation);
        fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_ANSWERS_FRAGMENT_WEBVIEW);
        fragmentInfo.setActionBarTitle(EikonApplication.getAppResources().getString(R.string.nav_option_quotes));
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);

        return fragment;
    }
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSearchTerm = getArguments().getString(SEARCH_TERM);
}
```

How do I fix the answersWebviewfragment to retrieve the searchterm??
P.S: the person who answers this will get around 100 points bounty and not just 50 , once your answer is approved as correct

Comment: Aren't you defining `OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT` before `mSearchView.getText()` has a value?

Comment: is BaseSearch.java an activity that then shows SearchFragment? or does SearchFragment extend BaseSearch?

Comment: OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT is in a different class(Awebfragment), I have imported the searchfragment class for the searchview class to be there.However, I am sure thats not the right way, even if i define searchview before output_encironment as something it wont help me get the dynamic values from previous class which is searchfragment, how do i pass on the value contained in msearchview or searchterm so i can use it in the url on AWebviewfragment class

Comment: @drees these are all fragments and seatchfragment does extend basesearch.java

Comment: Base classes shouldn't hold a view, move the mSearchView to another fragment and then save the entered string in BaseSearch.java as a variable. Then in SearchFragment, instead of calling mSearchView.getText(), call BaseSearch.getEnteredText() and use that. If you still are having problems, i'll post a complete answer

Comment: @drees no luck so far, however for better explanation, they are al lfragments and I have posted entire code of all the 3 classes (hadd to post only the essential stuff from class 3 (answers) as it was limited) , can you take a look and modify the same accordingly for only the essential lines of code that need to be changed and new to be added

Comment: Are you calling `__newInstance()` before it is added to the Activity? According to the docs about [setArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) it has to be called right after you instantiate the fragment. i.e. call `new answersWebviewfragment`

Comment: even if i do so, it will be something that will be specified after the variable OUT_ENVIRONMENT  is defined, say OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT ="https: //smething"+searchterm+""; followed by answerswebviewfrag newinstance {searchterm} . which would have searchterm declared within the method, how do i give it access outside the method and in output_env

Comment: Sharing information between fragments should be done through the activity hosting those fragments. Do you have only 1 MainActivity handling showing fragments?

Comment: I do have a main activity showing fragments, is there any specific adjustment i need to do there?

Comment: @JusticeBauer In your main activity, define a global variable: `String searchString = ""`. Add these two methods as well: `public String getSearchString() { return searchString; }` and `public void setSearchString(String s) { searchString = s; }`. Then, call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSearchString(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase())` to set the value. And use `public static String OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT = "...." + ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSearchString() +"....";` to retrieve the string. (contd..)

Comment: (...) Also, search for _Passing bundle data between fragments_ for tutorials on how to use `setArguments(Bundle)`.

Comment: where do i call ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSearchString(mSearchView.getText().toString().‌​toLowerCase())

Comment: where 'AnswersWebViewFragment .newInstanceForSearch()' is defined in your code? you call it when the class is used by HistoryAutoSuggestFragment.

Comment: Do I need to redefine msearchview which is defined in another class? It is not defined in main activity or nswerswebview fragment but in other related classes. As you can see fro mmy newinstance code in answers fragment, is there a way i can import parameter msearchview defined in another class?

Comment: Justice, you need to sort your question out and make it clear. You say you want to pass the text from `mSearchView`, why don't you pass it through the `__newInstance` method of `AnswersWebViewFragment`(which you call in the `runSearch` method) in the arguments `Bundle`? Then in the `onCreate` of `AnswersWebViewFragment` retrieve it from the arguments(like you did with `SEARCH_TERM`(is that the string you want?)) and **then** build the `OUTPUT_ENVIRONMENT` field.

Answer (score 0):

if your another class is fragment you can use `setArgument(bundle)` method of fragment passing string to another fragment. and to recieve these string you can `getArgument()` method.
[refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29)

Comment: Please check my edited question, I am already using the bundles in the AWEBVIEWFRAGMENT CLASS